# Makefile for input/output pairs

Tags: makefile

I have pairs of input/output files. I generate the name of the output file from a script: `output=$(generate input)`. For example the pairs could be:

```
in1.c      out1.o
in2.txt    data.txt
in3        config.sh
sub/in1.c  sub/out1.o
```

All those pairs obey the *same* set of rules in the makefile:

```
$(out): $(in) $(common) 
    $(run) $< > $@
```

**What is a concise and efficient way to write such a Makefile?**

I would rather avoid generating the Makefile from another script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't generate Makefile fragments from a script, but you could use an `include`:

```
INS := in1.c in2.txt in3 sub/in1.c

include rules.mk

rules.mk: Makefile
        rm -f $@
        for f in $(INS); do \
                out=`generate "$$f"`; \
                echo -e "$$out: $$f\n\t\$$(run) \$$<> > \$$@\n\n" >> $@; \
        done
```

Comment: Aaarrrggghhh! I was seconds away from submitting essentially the exact same answer...

Comment: Thanks. All great answers but this happens to suit me better.

Answer (score 3):

If you `include` a file gmake will try to generate and include it before any other targets. Combining this with a default rule should get you close to what you want

```
# makefile
gen=./generate.sh
source=a b c
run=echo

# Phony so the default rule doesn't match all
.PHONY:all
all:

# Update targets when makefile changes
targets.mk:makefile
    rm -f $@
    # Generate rules like $(target):$(source)
    for s in $(source); do echo "$$($(gen) $$s):$$s" >> $@; done
    # Generate rules like all:$(target)
    for s in $(source); do echo "all:$$($(gen) $$s)" >> $@; done

-include targets.mk

# Default pattern match rule
%:
    $(run) $< > $@
```

Testing with `generate.sh` like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

give me

```
$ make
rm -f targets.mk
for s in a b c; do echo "$(./generate.sh $s):$s" >> targets.mk; done
for s in a b c; do echo "all:$(./generate.sh $s)" >> targets.mk; done
echo a > 60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3
echo b > 3b5d5c3712955042212316173ccf37be
echo c > 2cd6ee2c70b0bde53fbe6cac3c8b8bb1
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is a concise and efficient way to write such a Makefile?

It is possible given a list of inputs and a shell script that generates output file name to generate targets, dependencies and rules using GNU make features:

```
all :

inputs := in1.c in2.txt in3 sub/in1.c
outputs :=

define make_dependency
  ${1} : ${2}
  outputs += ${1}
endef

# replace $(shell echo ${in}.out) with your $(shell generate ${in})
$(foreach in,${inputs},$(eval $(call make_dependency,$(shell echo ${in}.out),${in})))

# generic rule for all outputs, and the common dependency
# replace "echo ..." with a real rule
${outputs} : % : ${common}
    @echo "making $@ from $<"

all : ${outputs}

.PHONY : all
```

Output:

```
$ make
making in1.c.out from in1.c
making in2.txt.out from in2.txt
making in3.out from in3
making sub/in1.c.out from sub/in1.c
```

In the above makefile one little used by powerful GNU make construct is used: `$(eval $(call ...))`. It requests make to expand the macro to produce a piece of text and then evaluate that piece of text as a piece of makefile, i.e. make generates makefile of the fly.